# Rename [mobilesubstrate] to [cydia-substrate]

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, retag-request, synonym-request

After the release of the new evasi0n7 untethered jailbreak for iOS 7.x devices, MobileSubstrate was renamed to "Cydia Substrate". Either the [mobilesubstrate](/questions/tagged/mobilesubstrate) tag should be renamed to [cydia-substrate](/questions/tagged/cydia-substrate) or similar, or [cydia-substrate](/questions/tagged/cydia-substrate) should be a synonym to [mobilesubstrate](/questions/tagged/mobilesubstrate).

Comment: That's a lot of down-votes without a comment. Can someone chime in an explain why this is a bad idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know what's up with the down-votes here, but unless someone can explain a good reason *not* to do this I'm gonna put it down to a few knee-jerks twisted up over the mention of jailbreaking.

The tool clearly has been renamed; I've renamed (and synonymized) the tag to match.

Comment: Probably because of the controversy around TaiG

Comment: @anustart I know. I'm just saying some people aren't so smart